# Databricks to ElasticSearch error [scala/Product$class]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, elasticsearch, databricks, aws-databricks

When we are trying below code to push data from Databricks to ElasticSearch and we are getting below error.

- Elastic Search version ***6.1.3***
- Databricks runtime version:
  [image]

Added below jars in cluster libraries:

1. com.databricks:spark-xml_2.12:0.15.0
2. org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11:7.17.11
3. org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.13.11

Code:

```
df.write.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql") \
.option("es.nodes", hostname) \
.option("es.net.ssl", ssl) \
.option("es.resource", f"{index}/_doc") \
.option("es.mapping.id", "id") \
.mode("overwrite") \
.save()
print("complete")
```

tried to add below line but same error:

```
.option( "es.nodes.wan.only", "true" )
```

Error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Product$class
```

Comment: You're using libraries compiled against different versions of Scala: the DBR uses 2.12, spark-xml uses 2.12, elasticsearch-spark 2.11, and scala-reflect 2.13. You should be using consistent versions of Scala when managing dependencies; try removing the spark-xml library (included already in DBR) and the scala-reflect (not needed), and then change the ES library to org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-spark-30_2.12 (instead of _2.11)

Comment: Thank you so much @ZachKing. That error gone now. Getting new error now.. any inputs on this error?                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                 
Error => Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 5.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 5.0 (TID 12) (10.243.131.134 executor 1): org.apache.spark.util.TaskCompletionListenerException: Could not write all entries for bulk operation

Comment: Using org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-spark-30_2.12:8.8.2 now

Comment: that's the generic error of a Spark Task failing. Usually there is more buried in the full stacktrace; followed the "Caused by: ..." parts of the stacktrace until you find a more meaningful cause of the error (usually the bottom-most one, which is the root of the stacktrace). If you can share your full stacktrace in the Question that would be helpful.

Comment: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 5.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 5.0 (TID 12) (10.243.131.134 executor 1): org.apache.spark.util.TaskCompletionListenerException: Could not write all entries for bulk operation [10/10]. Error sample (first [5] error messages):
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last).   
 
 ---> 22     .save() // cant put all error stack here but error is at this line

Comment: remaining part => 
File /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/instrumentation_utils.py:48, in _wrap_function.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     46 start = time.perf_counter()
     47 try:
---> 48     res = func(*args, **kwargs)
     49     logger.log_success(
     50         module_name, class_name, function_name, time.perf_counter() - start, signature

Comment: Caused by: IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2023-07-12 07:42:09" is malformed at " 07:42:09"
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3) (10.243.131.137 executor 0): org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopParsingException: Cannot parse value [2023-07-12 07:42:09] for field [lastupdateddate]